# How can I parse string using square brackets as a delimiter in Java?

Tags: java, split, zoneddatetime

I have a class that parses ZonedDateTime objects using`.split()` to get rid of all the extra information I don't want.

**My Question:** Is there a way to use square brackets as delimiters that I am missing, OR how do I get the time zone ([US/Mountain]) by itself without using square brackets as delimiters?

I want the String timeZone to look like "US/Mountian" or "[US/Mountian]

**What I've Tried:**
Ive tried `wholeThing.split("[[-T:.]]?)` and `wholeThing.split("[%[-T:.%]]")` but those both give me `00[US/Mountain]`

I've also tried `wholeThing.split("[\\[-T:.\\]])` and `wholeThing.split("[\[-T:.\]")` but those just give me errors.

**(part of) My Code:**

```
 //We start out with something like   2016-09-28T17:38:38.990-06:00[US/Mountain]

    String[] whatTimeIsIt = wholeThing.split("[[-T:.]]"); //wholeThing is a TimeDateZone object converted to a String
    String year = whatTimeIsIt[0];
    String month = setMonth(whatTimeIsIt[1]);
    String day = whatTimeIsIt[2];
    String hour = setHour(whatTimeIsIt[3]);
    String minute = whatTimeIsIt[4];
    String second = setAmPm(whatTimeIsIt[5],whatTimeIsIt[3]);
    String timeZone = whatTimeIsIt[8];
```

Comment: Why don't you parse a ZonedDateTime string like that using .... you know .... `ZonedDateTime.parse()`? --- Anyway, your question is unclear on what output you want. What do you want the `timeZone` string to be? `-06:00`? `US/Mountain`? Please clarify. --- But, it would be better to *use* the regex, rather than trying to use `split()`, i.e. using `Pattern` and `Matcher`, so you can get the appropriate pieces using the `group(x)` method. If you don't know regex, now would be the time to learn.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to be able to just get the timezone from the String?

Comment: Edited to clarify

Comment: @andreas because I wanted practice doing it myself and because ZonedDateTime.parse() doesn't give me exactly what I want. My class does, except for this part that I'm stuck on.

Comment: *Curious:* In what way doesn't `ZonedDateTime.parse()` not give you what you want?

Comment: @Andreas I couldn't find many examples and the ones I did find didn't look any different than what I already had. Either way I like it better this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `split()` is the right idea.

```
String[] timeZoneTemp = wholeThing.split("\\[");
String timeZone = timeZoneTemp[1].substring(0, timeZoneTemp[1].length() - 1);
```

Comment: The first line gives me the error "Unclosed character class"

Comment: You forgot to add () after .length though :)

Comment: If you're just looking for the `[` character, then splitting on a regex is way overkill. Use `indexOf('[')` instead. Faster and clearer on intent.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse the string yourself, use a regular expression to extract the values.

Don't use a regex to find characters to split on, which is what [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) does.

Instead, use a regex with capture groups, compile it using [`Pattern.compile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile-java.lang.String-), obtain a [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) on your input text using [`matcher()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matcher-java.lang.CharSequence-), and check it using [`matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--).

If it matches you can get the captured groups using [`group()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-).

Example regex:

```
(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}).(\d+)[-+]\d{2}:\d{2}\[([^\]]+)\]
```

In a Java string, you have to escape the `\`, so here is code showing how it works:

```
String input = "2016-09-28T17:38:38.990-06:00[US/Mountain]";

String regex = "(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})T(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}).(\\d+)[-+]\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\[([^\\]]+)\\]";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println("Year    : " + m.group(1));
    System.out.println("Month   : " + m.group(2));
    System.out.println("Day     : " + m.group(3));
    System.out.println("Hour    : " + m.group(4));
    System.out.println("Minute  : " + m.group(5));
    System.out.println("Second  : " + m.group(6));
    System.out.println("Fraction: " + m.group(7));
    System.out.println("TimeZone: " + m.group(8));
} else {
    System.out.println("** BAD INPUT **");
}
```

*Output*

```
Year    : 2016
Month   : 09
Day     : 28
Hour    : 17
Minute  : 38
Second  : 38
Fraction: 990
TimeZone: US/Mountain
```

---

**UPDATED**

You can of course get all the same values using [`ZonedDateTime.parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-), which will also ensure that the date is *valid*, something none of the other solutions will do.

```
String input = "2016-09-28T17:38:38.990-06:00[US/Mountain]";

ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(input);
System.out.println("Year    : " + zdt.getYear());
System.out.println("Month   : " + zdt.getMonthValue());
System.out.println("Day     : " + zdt.getDayOfMonth());
System.out.println("Hour    : " + zdt.getHour());
System.out.println("Minute  : " + zdt.getMinute());
System.out.println("Second  : " + zdt.getSecond());
System.out.println("Milli   : " + zdt.getNano() / 1000000);
System.out.println("TimeZone: " + zdt.getZone());
```

*Output*

```
Year    : 2016
Month   : 9
Day     : 28
Hour    : 17
Minute  : 38
Second  : 38
Milli   : 990
TimeZone: US/Mountain
```

Comment: Thanks for the ZonedDateTime.parse() example, I couldn't find a decent one.

Comment: There probably were no examples of this, because you'd find the information easily by looking at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#method.summary) of `ZonedDateTime`.